# Is there a built-in way to proxy SSH through socks5?

Tags: ssh, nmap, socks, netcat

I have a Socks5 proxy that uses username/password authentication. I can use it with SSH using NCAT in the ProxyCommand: `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy-auth username:password --proxy socks5.proxy.domain:1080 %h %p" root@ssh.server.domain`

I'm using `ncat` from the NMAP package because the built-in `nc` command doesn't handle Socks5 proxy authentication.

Is there a simpler way of doing this without requiring nmap to be installed on the client?

Comment: Since afaik openssh has no native socks5 client support you need an external proxy command that does. (But you can configure the settings in your .ssh/config to have a more manageable command line.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for SOCKS5 proxy since `ProxyCommand` is generic enough that it provides support for **any** kind of proxy.

However `nc` does support SOCKS5 using `-X 5` so there's no need for `ncat`.

Comment: nc supports Socks5, but not username/password authentication, as far as I know

Comment: Ah I hadn't caught the authentication bit, I'm not sure about that through the basic `nc`.

Comment: Worth noting that `nc -x` is only available on `netcat-openbsd`, not on `netcat-traditional`. Since on MacOS there is no `netcat-openbsd` package, using `ncat` is a good alternative.